# It's possible extend AR relationships?

Tags: activerecord, yii, entity-relationship, yii-validation

I'd like know if there are a way to create my own rules to AR relationships or extends the existent HAS_MANY, BELONGS_TO etc?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you clearly specify an example of such a custom relationship?

Comment: Here you can find usefull information about CActiveRelation http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRelation

Answer (score 0):

Each AR relationships is created with the corresponding class.

```
    const BELONGS_TO='CBelongsToRelation';
    const HAS_ONE='CHasOneRelation';
    const HAS_MANY='CHasManyRelation';
    const MANY_MANY='CManyManyRelation';
    const STAT='CStatRelation';
```

These classes extend CActiveRelation » CBaseActiveRelation » CComponent.

You may be able to create your own AR relationship with a custom class extending CActiveRelation.

Comment: following your line of reasoning, I have 2 questions: 1 - can I create my own relationship class called – for exemple – polymorhic? 2 - where can I store my custom relation classes?

Comment: I never did that but I think you can.  
Look what CActiveRelation do and how relation classes extend it to know what your class must do. I didn't find any documentation about it.  
You can store your custom relation classes anywhere but be sure Yii knows where it is.